# Automating a Dialogue/Foley Reverb

Tags: reverb, glitch, digital, pop

I've got a scene I'm working on where a couple characters are having a conversation and the camera is in front of them walking with them tracking them as they walk through a whole office. The scene is one shot while they talk, and they walk through a lobby, into some offices, into a bigger conference room with bare walls. The dialogue is ADRed because the lapels didn't turn out too good.

So, I've got some dry dialogue I need to either worldize or automate a reverb to make it sound like the echo is changing throughout the rooms.

I've got TL Space - I haven't bought Altiverb yet, I really want it, but for now I've got only TL and Revibe.

Is there a trick you use to automate reverbs without them digitally clicking while they change to the different spaces?

The only way I can think of to do this is set up an A reverb and a B reverb and automate the sends crossfading into both and while the A reverb is not being used, have it switch to the next space after the B reverb is done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That approach will work for sure, and is a great method so long as DSP is available. Another way to go is to print your reverb returns to a track and then treat them as regular audio files. No need to worry about automating. Just be sure to keep copious notes or save your settings for when you need to go back and adjust a parameter -- or better yet, actually automate your reverbs as if they were going to run in real-time, print the return, and then inactivate the verb track. That way, if you need to make an adjustment, just re-activate the track and it's all right there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jay. I asked because I desperately need the DSP because of the SFX/music tracks being so numerous already. That's a great idea to print the returns - I'll try that out!

Comment: Worked perfectly. I have total control over the crossfade from one space to the next when I print it. Thanks a lot, Jay!

Comment: @Ryan, I used to do it your way using two aux tracks and switching back and forth, although I was told what @Jay suggests and it made things a lot easier. I remember the person who taught me this every time I mix!

Comment: @Justin Yeah! I gave it a bit of handle on either side of where the new space is supposed to be and it works like a charm - able to use whatever type of crossfade and manipulation of volume. Very useful. We all should reward @Jay with something for helping us out so much.

Comment: Pshhh(amusement expression)! thank you @Jay! this was huge help :)!